# get only two images by with relation Laravel Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I have tried to get only two image by using eloquent model like this

```
$data = Wedding::with(['weddingimage'=>function($q)use($req){
    $q->where('is_cover',0)
       ->limit(2);
    }])->withCount('weddingimage')
        ->limit(2)
        ->get();
```

but get only two images in first loop means index 0 and not in next index means 1,2.
please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: btw, if you add a limit in the eager load it will only limit the entire set of records it finds for the relationship in total for all parents ... so 2 in total, not 2 per parent

Comment: so , how can i get only two with per parent

Comment: @Shaddy see my answer for how to limit 2 per-parent (instead of 2 in total).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Laraval does not have this feature built-in.

If you add a limit in the relationship's eager-loading, it will only limit the total set of records it finds, 2 for all parents, not 2 per parent, while even the first parent may have more than 2 images.

But don't worry, [Jonas Staudenmeir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4848587/jonas-staudenmeir) toke his time developing the missing per-parent limit, see:
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

#### Usage:

You need to apply trait to both your models, in your case the models may look like:

```
class WeddingImage extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}

class Wedding extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;

    public function weddingimage() {
        return $this->hasMany(WeddingImage::class);
    }
}
```

Then simply chain `->limit(2)` in your eager-load query (which seems you already do).

Comment: It's a duplicate question, there are already plenty of answers.

Comment: Great , It working .Thank you so much.